# Seed SwiftUI Canvas CoreData database

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

How can I seed the SwiftUI Canvas CoreData database? I'm using a FetchRequest to get some CoreData data. I tried adding some info in the Previews like this:

```swift
struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let ctx = PersistentCloudKitContainer.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let dr = DoseRecord(context: ctx)
        dr.dose = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: Decimal(200))
        dr.date = Date()
        dr.drug = "Ibuprofen"

        try! ctx.save()
        
        return ctx
    }()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

But this adds a new record every single time the preview is rerendered. So how do I do this?

Comment: The following might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/62898993/12299030

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to be able to seed the database itself so I can see stuff on my list views.

Comment: Do you want to add that DoseRecord once?